# Using datetimeoffset dates in where clause date range filter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, utc, datetimeoffset

Using SQL Server 2016.  This is in a SP for a report. When given date range of 02/22/2017, report is including items for 02/21/2017. Dates are stored in the db as DateTimeOffset.

In this query I am amtrying to return on the 22nd, but I am also getting 21st.

@start and @end represent the date range entered by the user. @storeddate is the date from the db used to filter the report.  My plan is to convert the offset date then pull the 'date' part out to filter on, but it isnt working.

```
declare @start date = '2017-02-22';
declare @end date = '2017-02-22';
declare @storeddate datetimeoffset = '2017-02-22 00:00:19.0000000 +00:00';


;with dates as 
(
    select @storeddate as 'raw'
        , @storeddate AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' as offset
        , CONVERT(datetime, @storeddate) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' as dt
        , CONVERT(datetime, @storeddate AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') as d
        , CAST(CONVERT(datetime, @storeddate) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' as date) as 'casted' 
        , @start as 'start'
        , @end as 'end'

)

select * from dates
WHERE (
    CAST(CONVERT(datetime, @storeddate) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' as date) >= @start 
    AND CAST(CONVERT(datetime, @storeddate) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' as date) < DATEADD(day, 1, @end) )
```

Edit to add note:

Its kind of an odd scenario. This is an intranet web app used only in oregon.  The web developer used some javascript datepicker library that changed all his dates to UTC and he couldn't figure out how to change them back so he just stored them in the db as datetimeoffset.  So now I have to change all the reports to show the correct dates.  The 'At Time Zone' fixed the displaying of the dates in the reports, but it is not working in the where clauses for the date range filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the closing bracket on the CONVERT in the wrong place, so I was converting the @storeddate to date instead of the @storedate AT TIME ZONE.  So the answer was this:

```
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(datetime, @storeddate AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time') as date)
```

instead of

```
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(datetime, @storeddate) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' as date)
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to do with your timezones?  You're putting in @storeddate without an offset and then it looks like you're evaluating for Pacific time (-8:00, isn't it?).  It seems like that would shift the returned data.

Edit: Try using dateadd to modify the date:

```
declare @start date = '2017-02-22';
declare @end date = '2017-02-22';
declare @storeddate table (rawdate datetimeoffset) 
insert into @storeddate
values( '2017-02-22 00:00:19.0000000 +00:00')
,('2017-02-21 00:00:19.0000000 +00:00')
,('2017-02-22 00:18:19.0000000 +00:00')
,('2017-02-23 00:18:19.0000000 +00:00')

;with dates as 
(
    select rawdate as 'raw'
        , cast(dateadd(hh,-8,rawdate) as date)  as offset
        , @start as 'start'
        , @end as 'end'
        from @storeddate
)

select * from dates
WHERE (
    offset >= @start 
and    offset < DATEADD(day, 1, @end))
```

Comment: Its kind of an odd scenario. This is an intranet web app used only in oregon.  The web developer used some javascript datepicker library that changed all his dates to UTC and he couldn't figure out how to change them back so he just stored them in the db as datetimeoffset.  So now I have to change all the reports to show the correct dates.  The 'At Time Zone' fixed the displaying of the dates in the reports, but it is not working in the where clauses for the date range filters.

Comment: Try using the dateadd function to determine the offset instead of relying on 'At Time Zone.'  I think that only affects display, not the way the date is stored. I'm trying to paste an example and having formatting issues.